# all my files are green and not commited although I yesterday commited some files and uploaded

Tags: git

I have using git since 1 month and now I see a weird problem. I have over 100 files and yesterday I have changed 10 files and committed and uploaded to github. In my vscode there was no green files so all files were uploaded. Now I start vscode I see all files that I have are green.

What can I do now ?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with git here? To me it sounds like you just have problems with whatever git plugin vs-code is using. What is the result if you run a `git status`?